# Middleman: How can I render a different partial for mobile device?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, static, middleman, slim-lang

I'm building a landing page using Middleman right now (I'm not familiar with backend stuff). I split each sections into different partials (eg):

```
= partial "partials/_section-1"
= partial "partials/_section-2"
= partial "partials/_section-3"
```

I've been trying to display a different partial if user is browsing the website through mobile:

```
= partial "partials/_section-1"
- if mobile_device?
  = partial "partials/_section-2-mobile"
- else
  = partial "partials/_section-2"
= partial "partials/_section-3"
```

Is there any way I can achieve this? Probably something similar to Ruby's helper:

```
def mobile_device?
    if session[:mobile_param]
      session[:mobile_param] == "1"
    else
      request.user_agent =~ /Mobile|webOS/
    end
end
helper_method :mobile_device?
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the following function:

```
 def mobile_device?
   if session[:mobile_param]
     session[:mobile_param] == "1"
   else
     request.user_agent =~ /Mobile|webOS/
   end
end
```

Also, a Railscast with further information:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/199-mobile-devices

For a better Regexp, use the following site: http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/

---

Since you already have the same script, where's your question at?

Comment: I did but it doesn't work on Middleman. I'm getting this error every time:
`undefined local variable or method 'session'`

Answer (score 0):

Middleman generates static pages, so it is not at all involved when the client accesses the site. So there is no way Middleman can do that.

Your best bet is to use css or javascript.

Comment: Yes. True that. I was too ambitious with middleman at first :P